# FTP setup error (from IIS) Invalid Application Pool name

Tags: windows-8.1, ftp, iis

I have Windows 8.1 and I want to set up an FTP server (home ftp server, not public).

But when I Add an FTP site (from IIS manager), After complete setup, I get an error "`Invalid Application Pool Name`".

Any suggestions to help solve my problem?

Please see the attached image, which shows the error I get when I add an FTP site:

[image]

Comment: I think you need to add a screen shot of this `After complete setup, I get an error "Invalid Application Pool Name"`. What part of the setup where you see this, a visual would really be helpful. Otherwise, look at the app pool settings and assign the site to one that exists. This should be an option within the IIS manager interface of the FTP site at that level. See what the identity of that app pool is running as too.

Comment: @user1766169 From an elevated command prompt first run: `%windir%\system32\inetsrv` press enter, and then run `appcmd list apppool` and give a screen shot or something of the output. If it's small just paste as a comment I suppose. Just curious to see how you have those configured. I assume you're working with Windows 8 and IIS 8?

Comment: Could you upload a picture of your application pools tab in IIS?

Comment: @user1766169 . . . [**Command Line**
To specify the account identity for an application pool to use, use the following syntax: `appcmd set config /section:applicationPools /"[name=' string ']".processModel.identityType:LocalService`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771170(v=ws.10).aspx)... So try running: `appcmd set config /section:applicationPools /"[name=' string ']".processModel.identityType:LocalService` plugging in the correct variables for your environment and do this from an elevated command prompt. You could use `SpecificUser|NetworkService|LocalService|LocalSystem`

Answer (score 2):

I copied the

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationhost.config
```

file from another Windows Server, and replaced the old one with the problem, and the error was gone.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, however the ftp server still worked.
Also I managed to fix the error message:

1. create an application pool manually
2. open 'C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationhost.config
3. find the FTP site and manually add the application pool:

   ```
   <site name="YourFTPSiteName" id="24">
      <application path="/" applicationPool="YourCustomAppPool">
      ...
      </application>
      ...
   </site>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing a list of names in both sites and application pool I can't help too much. I would probably start with the "Advanced Settings" link for the site and ensure that the correct application pool is listed there. When you open the Advanced settings page you will see the first line has application pool. In the second column will either be a name or it will be blank. If it is blank or the name is wrong then you need to click on the ellipses to the right. This will open another page and you will be able to pick from a drop down list of application pool names.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by simply turning whole IIS feature off & then on.